# Search query custom path

Tags: content-search, content-editor

I'm trying to build a search query to find an item that is a child of the current item. Something like this:

```
custom:path|./_local/*
```

But this returns 0 results (should be 3 results). How do I do this?

Comment: Where are you executing the query? Is it a datasource?

Comment: Yes, it's the datasource field of a control/component

Comment: According to Sitecore's documentation just use **query:.//***
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/use-a-query-to-determine-the-data-source-context.html

Answer (score 0):

If this is the source query for a field, you can use:

```
query:../_local/*
```

For `Datasource Location` on a rendering you can put in:

```
./_local
```

Comment: 0 results. This is not for a field, but for the datasource for a component

Comment: @devzero I updated my answer for rendering datasource location

Comment: Does not work. What works is the absolute path "/sitecore/content/home/item/_Local/TextSpot". What does not work:  "./_local/TextSpot". Text spot is a controll on the "item"

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure "**_local**" is the actual item name in your case, following worked fine for me in the "Datasource location" rendering def. field:

```
query:.//*[@@name='**local**']
```